# Create GeoJSON GraphQL schema from third party library

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, express-graphql

I'm trying to use the [graphql-geojson](https://github.com/ghengeveld/graphql-geojson) library in an Apollo/Express app to serve GeoJSON responses.

The library provides the resolvers but I haven't found a way to add the types to my schema definition without writing them out by hand. And even then that hasn't proven that simple.

Another custom type, Date from [graphql-date](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-date), I can just declare in the schema as a custom scalar:

```
const typeDefs: DocumentNode = gql`
  scalar Date
  scalar PointObject

  type Station {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    geom: PointObject
    created: Date!
  }
  ...
}
```

However, declaring PointObject as scalar allows you to get the full GeoJSON (which is OK) but results in errors:

> "GraphQLError: Field \"geom\" must not have a selection since type \"GeoJSONPoint\" has no subfields."

when you try to return a sub-selection of `geom`, e.g.:

```
{
  stations {
    id
    name
    geom {
      coordinates
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way merge the types provided by the library with my schema?

Answer (score 1):

Apollo's `graphql-tools` library includes [a mergeSchemas function](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/graphql-tools.html#mergeSchemas) which can combine multiple schemas and bits of schema together.  You should be able to use this to build one big schema out of your type definitions (untested):

```js
import * as GeoJSON from 'graphql-geojson';
import { mergeSchemas } from 'graphql-tools';

const typeDefs = `
  type Station {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    geom: PointObject
    created: Date!
  }
`;

const schema = mergeSchemas({
  schemas: [Object.values(GeoJSON), typeDefs]
});
```

(Note that [the types graphql-geojson defines](https://github.com/ghengeveld/graphql-geojson/blob/master/index.js#L13) are kind of involved; they are definitely not a single scalar type, and I wouldn't want to try to retype them in my schema definition if it could be avoided.)